# Read rails encrypted credentials in webpacker react app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpacker

With .env files, it was easy to inject variables in webpacker js packs. Since 5.2, you can use the encrypted secrets, but is there a way to read (decrypt) them in inject some of them on webpacker build time?

Answer (score 10):

You can read from credentials and pass that value to Webpacker.

1. Create a `config/initializers/webpacker.rb` file.
2. Pass it to the `Webpacker::Compiler` through file above.

   ```rb
   Webpacker::Compiler.env['VALUE'] = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:value)
   ```
3. Read it as `console.log(process.env.VALUE)`.
4. If you want to try it on `development`, you need to add these to the `bin/webpack-dev-server`:

   ```rb
   require_relative '../config/application'
   Rails.application.initialize!
   ```

Sources:

- http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=ja&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fqiita.com%2Ftakeyuweb%2Fitems%2F61e6ba07fe0df3079041
- https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2794
- https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/830f47695ea3f40dcbab5ee117769ab67b96af36/docs/env.md

Comment: thats brilliant!

Comment: `require_relative '../config/environment'` might server as shortcut for the webpack-dev-server snippet above

Comment: @WasifHossain do you mean as removing the second step?

Comment: i meant it as equivalent to the 4th step